# from one dagger2 module how to access the SharedPreferences provided in another dagger2 module

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

Having the SharedPreferences provided from one dagger2 module,  in another dagger2 module would like to use it,
how to do it?

the code below seems not working.

/** the component */

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(DataManagerModule::class, 
                             AnotherModule::class))
interface DataManagerComponent {
    fun getDataManager() : DataManager
    fun getSharedPreferences() : SharedPreferences
}
```

/** the module 1 */

```
@Module
class DataManagerModule(@ApplicationContext private val appContext: Context) {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @ApplicationContext
    fun provideApplicationContext(): Context = appContext

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideSharedPreferences(): SharedPreferences {
        return appContext.getSharedPreferences(appContext.packageName, 
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }
}
```

/** the module 2 */

```
@Module
class AnotherModule(private val config1: String?, private val config2: Int?) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideClass2(context: Context): Class2 {

        if (config2 == null) {

            // how to get the preferences???
            // getSharedPreferences().edit().getInt(Constants.Settings, -1)

        }

        return class2(config1, config2, context)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the issue or problem you're facing? If you need those preference you can just add them to the method signature, the same way you already do with your context. `provideClass2(context: Context, prefs: SharedPreferences)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since all these artifacts share the same scope, and the component is built using both modules, you should be able to simply add `SharedPreferences` as a parameter to `provideClass2()` in order to use it in the construction of `Class2`, like so:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
internal fun provideClass2(context: Context, prefs: SharedPreferences): Class2 {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already defined how to retrieve SharedPreferences from DataManagerModule class you can simply change

```
internal fun provideClass2(context: Context): Class2 {
       ...
}
```

to

```
internal fun provideClass2(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences): Class2 {
       ...
}
```

Have another class extend the Application class and declare it to the AndroidManifest like so:

```
class App: Application() {

    lateinit var dataManagerComponent: DataManagerComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        dataManagerComponent = DaggerDataManagerComponent.builder()
                .dataManagerModule(DataManagerModule(this))
                .anotherModule(AnotherModule("config1", 123))
                .build()
    }
}
```

Modify your component to include an inject function

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(DataManagerModule::class,
        AnotherModule::class))
interface DataManagerComponent {
    fun getDataManager() : DataManager
    fun getSharedPreferences() : SharedPreferences
    // The activity/fragment you will need the values
    fun inject(target: MainActivity)
}
```

Then inject it to the activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var class2: Class2

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        (application as App).dataManagerComponent.inject(this)


        Log.i("CLASS2", class2.toString())
    }
}
```